# Is it possible to add the output of a generator when making a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, generator

Is it possible to make a generator's output be added into a list creation, without making a nested list in Python?
I have tried the following code, but it only gives me a generator object, and not the items.

```py
x = 5
expected_list = [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]
list = [3, 0 for i in range(x), 3]
print(list)
```

I get this error whenever trying to run this code:

```
    list = [3, 0 for i in range(x), 3]
            ^^^^
SyntaxError: did you forget parentheses around the comprehension target?
```

If I put parentheses around `0 for i in range(x)`, I get the list

```py
[3, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001A065179A10>, 3]
```

I would like for the generator object to return `0, 0, 0, 0, 0`, without creating a list inside of my list.

Comment: Just `[3, *([0]*x), 3]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack it:

```
[3, *(0 for i in range(x)), 3]
```